# Is Pex Silverlight 5 compatible?

Tags: silverlight, pex

I've tried to get pex working with Silverlight 5 environment (Framework 4.0) and I was not able because Pex is allways trying to find the System references (System.Windows, System.Net, etc...) of the old version v2.5.0 isntead of the proper one v5.0.5

Any clue?

Thanks and regards,
Oscar